# Scaling y axis and plot

Tags: plotting, scaling

NOW，i plot a graph.I want to make the graph and y axis 10^6 times smaller,making the -5*10^6 to -5 in Y axis,at the same time,the graphy is not change.I'm going to change the vertical coordinate from Mpa to Pa.This is what I drew.

[image]
This is what i mean
[image]
If i use function of `PlotRange`,it only plots part of the data,but i want to plot all datas.

```
x = Import["D:\\ab\\test.csv"];
col = Length[x];

row = Length[x[[1]]];

p = {{ListLinePlot[Table[x[[i, j]], {i, col}, {j, 2}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-20000000, 4000000}}, 
     Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, Frame -> {False, True, True, True}, 
     Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.001]]}, {ListLinePlot[
     Table[x[[i, j]], {i, col}, {j, 3, 4}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-20000000, 4000000}}, PlotRange -> All,
      Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, Frame -> {False, True, True, True}, 
     Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.001]]},
   {ListLinePlot[Table[x[[i, j]], {i, col}, {j, 5, 6}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-20000000, 4000000}}, PlotRange -> All,
      Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, Frame -> {False, True, True, True}, 
     Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.001]]},
   {ListLinePlot[Table[x[[i, j]], {i, col}, {j, 7, 8}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-20000000, 4000000}}, PlotRange -> All,
      Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, Frame -> {False, True, True, True}, 
     Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.001]]},
   {ListLinePlot[Table[x[[i, j]], {i, col}, {j, 9, 10}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-20000000, 4000000}}, PlotRange -> All,
      Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, Frame -> {False, True, True, True}, 
     Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.001]]},
   {ListLinePlot[Table[x[[i, j]], {i, col}, {j, 11, 12}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-20000000, 4000000}}, PlotRange -> All,
      Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"纵向位置/m"}, Axes -> False, 
     PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.001]]}};
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][p, Spacings -> 0]
```

Comment: Have you tried rescaling the y-values of the points themselves before plotting them?

Comment: @ bbgodfreyWow, that's right.Thank you .and i also have a problem,`Import ` excel data is stored as a list by row, how by column to store.

Comment: See [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) option.

Comment: Your comment could be posed as a new question.  If you do, provide some sample data for the reader to consider.  By the way @Edmund 's approach also works for changing the scaling.

Comment: @beginner If you want to switch rows and columns you could use the Transpose function on your data after loading it in.

Comment: @ Edmund i read the help document about `ScalingFunction`,and i still dont know how to use it to scaling graph.i consider `ScalingFunction` for log or Reverse.

Comment: @beginner, can you upload the file `test.csv`   or similar synthetic data so we can provide direct help?

Comment: @Nate Thank you.`Transpose` can slove my problem.